# Eclipse finds false error for @Override

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Eclipse ([Eclipse 3.8.1](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.1-201209141540/) from [STS 3.1](http://www.springsource.org/sts/)) finds false error for @Override

```
public class Class1 implements Comparable<Class1> {
...
@Override
public int compareTo(Class1 o) {
```

copmareTo() has markers:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method compareTo(Class1 ) of type Class1 must override a superclass method
    - implements java.lang.Comparable<com.funshion.base.mc.entity.McImp>.compareTo
```

The first message is wrong.

.project content

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>ProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Java version must be 1.6,
as @Override annotation arrived with Java 6.